# How does composer resolve the `dumpautoload` command?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, command-line-arguments

Using `Composer version 1.8.6 2019-06-11 15:03:05` the `dumpautoload` command works with all the following variations

```sh
composer dump-autoload
composer dumpautoload
composer dumpautoloa
composer dumpautolo
composer dumpautol
composer dumpauto
composer dumpaut
composer dumpau
composer dumpa
composer dump
composer dum
composer du
```

Until `composer d` which throws

> [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]
>     Command "d" is ambiguous (depends, dump-autoload and 1 more).

How are the commands resolved? I understand that `dumpautoload` is set as an alias to `dump-autoload` in [composer source here](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/522ea033a3c6e72d72954f7cd019a3b75e28f391/src/Composer/Command/DumpAutoloadCommand.php#L30)

```php
class DumpAutoloadCommand extends BaseCommand
{
   protected function configure()
   {
      $this->setName('dump-autoload')->setAliases(array('dumpautoload'))
```

and `setAliases` in the `composer/RootPackage.php` [source here](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/837ad7c14e8ce364296e0d0600d04c415b6e359d/src/Composer/Package/RootPackage.php#L124) only assign the aliases to the `private $aliases;` property

```php
public function setAliases(array $aliases)
{
    $this->aliases = $aliases;
}
```

But how are the other variations resolved?

Comment: If I had to take a wild guess, it could be using `similar_text()`

Comment: `similar_text('du', 'dumpautoload');` => 2 which I don't think is enough

Comment: And `similar_text('dumpautoload', 'dumnautoload');` => 11/12 but ironically `dumnautoload` doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Composer builds up upon `symfony/console`, and the code to search for a command is located in `Symfony\Component\Console\Application::find`, which can be found at https://github.com/symfony/console/blob/master/Application.php#L596. Basically, all registered commands are checked until the shortest, clearly identifiable length - so the approach with `similar_text` is already too sophisticated ;)

Comment: Interesting! I also found another instance of `setAliases` which passes the command to `validateName($name)` which does some preg_matching